# Maven and spring-boot-dependencies

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have a Maven multimodule project that has some old version of spring-boot-dependencies set as parent in the main pom.xml. All submodules inherit spring boot dependencies from this main pom.xml.

And this is fine but in one of the new submodule (being also multi module) I want to use the newest spring boot version without changing the one that is being used (together with all the dependencies) across the project.

Is there a way to cleverly override the version of spring boot (with all its dependencies) derived from parent and use different one in submodule?
I tried to setup explicit version of spring boot within `<spring-boot.version>` property in all new module's submodules' pom.xml files but without luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to cleverly override the version of spring boot (with all its dependencies) derived from parent and use different one in submodule?

No. When you use a specific version of Spring Boot as the parent (or grandparent, etc), you're saying that's the version of Spring Boot that you want to use.

> I tried to setup explicit version of spring boot within  property in all new module's submodules' pom.xml files but without luck.

If this did work you'd end up with the parent from Spring Boot version X with configuration such as the Maven plugin management for that version alongside dependencies from Spring Boot version Y. This mixture of versions could lead to strange and unexpected behaviour that would be very hard to diagnose.

If you want to be able to mix and match versions like this, you should avoid using the parent from Spring Boot and should import `spring-boot-dependencies` instead:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This gives you complete control over the version at the cost of having to define any plugin management that you need yourself. It's also worth noting that you can't override properties from an imported pom.

Comment: Ok, just to be sure we're on the same page - so one import replaces the `<parent>` tag and goes into the main pom.xml (for the old spring boot dependencies) and the second one into the new submodule to override it, correct? If adding this import into the new submodule is straightforward, the second change - to the main pom.xml - seems to be quite a big... Thanks!

Comment: Correct. A second import will override the first. Alternatively, you could use a property for the first import in the parent and then override that property in the child.